# one server many http domains and one https domain

Tags: apache, http, redirect, https

I haven't been able to solve an issue with my server: 
I use a linux server,  Debian 7.0 distro.
I am hosting many different domains, all except one, are plain http domains which I can easily redirect using virtual hosts on httpd.conf or apache2.conf.  The problem I can't solve is with one domain,  which requires SSL,  so I need to force redirect http to https.  I worked on virtual host of that specific domain,  and managed to get http to https redirect,  but now,  all remaining domains are forced also to the https domain.  How can achieve each http domain redirects to it's own,  but also the requires SSL domain redirects to https?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some versions of Apache, I know as late as version 2.2, you will need to include the line:

NameVirtualHost *:80

before your virtual host lines. I can't be sure that this is your problem, but I just had the exact same thing happening to me on Arch, which apparently doesn't have the latest Apache.

Comment: Thanks I'll test it.  Did ypu refer to including that line in ports.conf or httpd.conf?